# Python xlwt format entire row or column

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I would like to write an excel file, and I want to be able to set the format of the entire row. I see that when I write cells I can decide the format, but the empty rows underneath do not have the same format.

Right now my solution is to write empty rows with the formatting I want. I found that Pandas ExcelWriter has this function. http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html

Is it posible to do the same with xlwt?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use xlwt and not XlsxWriter?

Comment: The project that I am working on used xlwt so far, I was looking for a solution in that context. I see that there are other options.